# Child combinator not working on unordered list

Tags: html, css

I have a simple unordered list where I'm trying to style all parent `<li>` items so they are uppercase.

```css
ul > li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>UPPERCASE</li>
  <li>UPPERCASE
    <ul>
      <li>Lowercase</li>
      <li>Lowercase</li>
      <li>Lowercase</li>
      <li>Lowercase</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>UPPERCASE</li>
  <li>UPPERCASE</li>
</ul>
```

The method above was suggested by [this article](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/), but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? It transforms the "Lowercase" text to uppercase because those `li`s are direct children of a `ul` element, just like your selector says...

Comment: In the article you provide, they use an `ol` element as sub-list, which is not impacted by the CSS rule (that target `ul`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That styles every `li` which is a child of a `ul` … which is *all* of them. Additionally, the default value for `text-transform` is `inherit` so the descendants will pick up the `uppercase` value from the parent anyway.

You need to write a selector which uniquely matches the children of the outermost one, and change the default to something different.

For example:

```css
li { 
  text-transform: none;
}
:not(li) > ul > li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>UPPERCASE</li>
  <li>UPPERCASE
    <ul>
      <li>Lowercase</li>
      <li>Lowercase</li>
      <li>Lowercase</li>
      <li>Lowercase</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>UPPERCASE</li>
  <li>UPPERCASE</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result , use below option

ul > li will select all li elements of ul which includes the Lowercase li elements

li > ul > li will select all ul elements under li element and apply initial to retain initial style

```
ul > li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

li > ul > li{
  text-transform: initial;
}
```

Code sample-  https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/VXpvWG
Run code snippet to test

```css
   ul > li {
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    li > ul > li{
      text-transform: initial;
    }
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

    <ul>
      <li>UPPERCASE</li>
      <li>UPPERCASE
        <ul>
          <li>Lowercase</li>
          <li>Lowercase</li>
          <li>Lowercase</li>
          <li>Lowercase</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>UPPERCASE</li>
      <li>UPPERCASE</li>
    </ul>
```